# Plot multiple lines on a graph from ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, bokeh

I have two variables of the same unit I want to plot on the same x-axis with Bokeh. Seems like plot.multi_line is the right tool but I can't find the right syntax from the doc. What I tried (gathered from doc):

```
# df is a pandas DataFrame with contains 3 columns x, y1, y2

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
plot=figure()   
plot.multi_line(['x','x'], ['y1', 'y2'],  source=source)
```

Alternatively tried:

```
plot.multi_line(xs=['x','x'], ys=['y1', 'y2'],  source=source)
```

Results in

> RuntimeError: 
>   Supplying a user-defined data source AND iterable values to glyph methods is
>   not possibe. Either:
>
> Pass all data directly as literals:
>
> p.circe(x=a_list, y=an_array, ...)
>
> Or, put all data in a ColumnDataSource and pass column names:
>
> source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=a_list, y=an_array))
>      p.circe(x='x', y='x', source=source, ...)

Doc give this example:

```
p.multi_line([[1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 6, 6]], [[2, 1, 4], [4, 7, 8, 5]],
         color=["firebrick", "navy"], alpha=[0.8, 0.3], line_width=4)
```

I obviously don't want to pass the values with raw lists. I don't get it, I need a little help.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I feel silly, simply doing:

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)
plot=figure()   
plot.line('x','y1',  source=source, line_color="red")
plot.line('x','y2',  source=source, line_color="blue")
```

does the trick, as it would do in Matplotlib... I got confused with this "plot.multi_line" function (I now don't get why I would used that, but well).

Comment: `multi_line` is useful when you have a single "logical" line that is made up of separate, disconnected sub-lines. An analogue would be using `patches` to draw polygons for countries. A country border may have several disconnected pieces (e.g. islands offshore) but still represent a single logical entity.